# How to pronounce "router" in English

Tags: pronunciation

How to pronounce *router* in English? I've heard it pronounced two different ways, *ruter* and *router*. Which is correct?

Comment: Perhaps rowter is used so often because rooter also has a sexual connotation and may be awkward for some to say or hear

Answer (score 16, accepted):

*Router* has two different meaning, and it can have two different pronunciations, depending on the English dialect.

- A device which sends data to the appropriate parts of a computer network

  [image: screenshot]

  - British English: /ˈruːtə(r)/
  - North American English: /ˈruːtər/ or /ˈraʊtər/
- An electric tool which cuts shallow lines in surfaces

  [image: screenshot]

  - British English: /ˈraʊtə(r)/
  - North American English: /ˈraʊtər/

This is the pronunciation reported from the *Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary*; the *New Oxford American Dictionary* reports /ˈraʊdər/ as pronunciation in both the cases.

Comment: In Australia, people are more likely to use /aʊ/ to disambiguate route from root - but that's because [root](http://australiandictionary.net/root) has an entirely different meaning.

Comment: As you say, Brits are pretty consistent in distinguishing *route* (pathway, pronounced *root*), from *rout* (cut a groove, or cause to retreat in disorder, pronounced *rowt*). But in my experience, most Americans call the network device a *rowter*, even though they still say [Root 66](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/U.S._Route_66). My guess is it's because they think the network and the carpentry routers are both "tools", so they both get the same pronunciation, even though it makes no etymological sense.

Comment: I come from one region and live in another in the US, and in both places, it is not unlikely to hear someone say something along the lines of: "the postman has a route (rOWt) on Route (rOOt) 1"

Comment: @snailplane But *root* is /rʊt/ for many of us, just as in *foot* and *put*, so there is no issue. Still, *route* is certainly /raʊt/, and so *router*  follows directly.

Answer (score 5):

I would say its like **rowtur**, where *row* rhymes with *bow* in bowwow. (US English)
But *route* can be pronounced like **rowt** or **rute**.
I've only heard **rowtur** for a computer network router, or for a router used for woodworking.